# Creating a log in for transformice

Tags: bots

I heard the protocol changed..what now? IS there anychance i can make a bot now?
I am trying to make a sort of 'bot' which can connect to a Transformice server(its a game)and post messages.

Anyway, I'm having some trouble understanding how to send packets in python, and how to correctly encode them.

The packets code i found are from the API on this site : http://kikoo.formice.com/doku.php?id=start 
Logging on is my problem.
I know I need to be using sockets, and I need to be using struct.pack, but how exactly can I send it?

I don't know if i made the connection the right way. 
This is what they tell me to do:
(Establishing a connection)

To connect to the server, send a 28,1 packet to the server containing the protocol version, the connection key and the number 0x17ed (The loader's size).
Logging in

After you connect to the server successfully, the next thing to do is actually log in and join the game. If you already have a good packet building framework, this should be simple enough.

To log in, simply send an old protocol 26,4 packet with your username, the password hashed by sha256, a room to join3) and an origin url – “http://www.transformice.com/Transformice.swf?n=1335716949138” + base64(sha256(sha256(password)+salt)) (see on packet infos) seems to work just fine. 
An example piece code that sends a login packet would be marvellous.

(this is what i got so far)

```
import socket
import struct
import time
from struct import pack, unpack
import hashlib
import sys

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

s.connect(('www.transformice.com', 80))

print ('Connected')
```

I heard the protocol changed..what now?